# How do you select the columns displayed in Pending Changes?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Open up TFS Pending Changes. Can you add / remove columns to that display? I thought it was tied to the selected query, but change the columns in that query did nothing for the results displayed in Pending Changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that the columns displayed in the work items channel of the pending changes view are fixed and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 2):

you cannot add columns but if you open the query your using and sort by the columns you have added it sorts the work items by that same column although that column is not displayed in the pending changes pane.

Comment: Boo Microsoft! Thanks adam. I have taken to adding some more "key" text to the work item's Title so that it will be in the Pending Changes window.